# html input file - how to save selected file when selecting new file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to create an upload panel like facebook, but I've got a trouble with `<input type="file" />`.

Here is facebook upload image panel:

[image]

My trouble is: if I click *add more* (like image above), that means the `<input type="file" />` will be clicked again. So, the value will be overridden.

After that, if I click `submit` button, only 1 image can be uploaded.

My jquery code to upload looks like this:

```
function Upload(evt, id)
{
    var file = document.getElementById("file");
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(file.files[i].name, file.files[i]);
    }
    formData.append("id", id);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Upload",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('upload successful...');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('upload failed...');
        }
    });
}
```

The first line: `var file = document.getElementById("file");`. It means: get the latest value of `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />` (no keep the selected file before).

Can you tell me how to get all the selected files? (I don't talk about `multiple`).

Thank you!

Comment: What you're looking for is an element array. If you can append `<input type="file" name="file[]">` then you're all set. You will get all the files in an array.

Comment: @DaveChen I still don't understand that how can `name="file[]"` keep the selected file before and get new selected file. Can you tell me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My trouble is: if I click add more (like image above), that means the  will be clicked again. So, the value will be overridden."

Here's the underlying problem with your script:
"You can't set the value of a file picker from a script" so no direct manipulation of form will work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#File_inputs

You can't manipulate file inputs from javascript in any meaningful way (for obvious security reasons), you can only read them. However, you can manipulate the DOM. What facebook and other multi-part pickers actually do is create and destroy file input elements in order to allow the flows they want, rather than try to bind anything to the file value of the input.

There are a lot of plugins that handle this complexity for you, but it's pretty doable to get it working once you understand the problem you're working around.

#### further clarification:

yup, it sounds like you're thinking about it right now! just think of file inputs as read-only, and use another variable to store all your values, and any function to deal with showing previews in the dom reads from that rather than binding directly from the file input.

One extra thing I would add in response to `But the value can only append, not remove :((`, is that you shouldn't store the values in FormData if you might need to remove values. Instead just use a regular object to store all the values you want to add/modify, and then construct the object when the user submits the form. Something along the lines of this:

```
var myFormDataObject = {}; // can store inputs in this
// watch onchange and add/remove from myFormDataObject

function sendStuff(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var key in myFormDataObject) {
    formData.append(key, myFormDataObject[key]);
  }
  // then post/put/patch/etc the form
}
```

Comment: A plugin to `cheat` javascript? it's hard to understand :((

Comment: not to cheat javascript, but to allow for complex user interface behavior around the `appearance` of a single file input. Have a look at the source code of popular javascript file uploaders and you will see how they clone and remove elements rather than actually use the same element each time https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1047

Comment: Thanks. mmm... I just think a new solution. I'm not sure it's the best way, please checking it help me. I will catch event `onchange` of `<input type="file" />`, and create another function to append the selected file to `var formData = new FormData()`, but not uploading. If appearance new event `onchange`, I will continue appending the `new selected file` to `formData`. So, `formData` is used like a global variable for `preview image function` and `upload image function`. Is that good? But the value can only append, not remove :((

Comment: edited answer. basically just put one layer of abstraction between UX and FormData